# How to receive data from a View to a Controller and then pass to a new View

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, model-view-controller

Sup, everyone! Heres the deal... Im trying to pass values that i got from a view using @Html.ActionLink to a controller and then pass to a new view. Ill provide some codes below for better understand.

i've tried creating a ViewModel with the variables that are identical to the values that i need and in the controller i try to pass values from the view using ActionResult overload to encapsulate the ViewModel Class, so when i try to show these results returning to a new view, it gets null exception. Im new to C#, if anyone knows something else better that i could use in this situation i would really apreciate the help, thanks!

part of my view with the values that i want:

```
<ul>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.Pedido + " - " + item.Status, "Index", "Pedidostatus", new { pedido = item.Pedido, status = item.Status }, null)</li>
            }
        </ul>
```

i only need 'pedido' and 'status' to be received in Pedidostatus controller, so im using Html.ActionLink to pass the values as you all can see.

ViewModel that i created:

```
public class PedidosViewModel
    {
        public string PedidoVM { get; set; }
        public string StatusVM { get; set; }
    }
```

The controller i want to receive the views values(Pedidostatus):

```
using Status_Pedido_Venda.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Status_Pedido_Venda.Controllers
{
    public class PedidostatusController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Pedidostatus
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Show(string pedido, string status)
        {
            PedidosViewModel viewModel = new PedidosViewModel()
            {
                PedidoVM = pedido,
                StatusVM = status
            };


            return View("Index", viewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

My new view that i want to show the values got from the first view through the controller:

```
@model Status_Pedido_Venda.ViewModels.PedidosViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@if(Model.PedidoVM != null && Model.StatusVM != null)
{
    <h2>@Model.PedidoVM</h2>
    <h2>@Model.StatusVM</h2>
}
```

I expected to show the results got from the first view in my new view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action name should be **Show** not index

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink(item.Pedido + " - " + item.Status, "Show", "Pedidostatus", new { pedido = item.Pedido, status = item.Status }, null)</li>
```